# Match multiple values in substring and use specific category

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am having a string and I am trying to match multiple values for this string.

I think I figured out how to match the string, BUT haven't yet figured out to get the wanted value in the cell.

For matching I am using:

```
=sumproduct(isnumber(search(transpose($B$17:$B$20),A2)))
```

Below is my example:

[image]

This is an example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IN2hMcpEc1sZ7JGP3XGD3AJMYnKt2RlsLIlvk8vXtbo/edit?usp=sharing

How can I use the value from the matching table?

I appreciate you replies!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(PROPER(A2:A9), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B13:B16)), B13:C16, 2, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot! Is it also possible to use a default value if no value is found? I appreciate your reply!

Comment: @Carol.Kar try: `=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(PROPER(A2:A9), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B13:B16)), B13:C16, 2, ), "no match")))`